# How to call a WP function from another site on the same box without SYMLINK

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, symlink

I want to call a WordPress function from another site without using SymLink. I do not want to embed an entire site, just bits and pieces.

To give a clearer picture and to answer a comment posted below on bits and pieces, take the blog [blog.butterflyvista.com](http://blog.butterflyvista.com) and the site [careerarbalest](http://www.careerarbalest.com). I placed the first part of 3 blog postings inside an iframe. I called the section "Insights by Sarah". I am not embedding the blog inside the main site. That leaves, as I say below, `Create Virtual Directory` feature of Plesk out.

I achieved my goal on VPS by creating a SYMLINK so that the blog appears as a sub-directory off my site without actually being a sub-directory. The blog exists and should exist in its domain. My site can then call a PHP function inside an iframe, which loads the WP content.

```
mysite1.com/Blogs/Blog1
mysite2.com/Blogs/Blog1

symlink: Blog1 [C:\...\theblog.com\httpdocs]
```

Inside the PHP code, I can then do:

```
$pathRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$pathWordpress = $pathRoot . '/Blogs/Blog1/wp-blog-header.php';
require($pathWordpress);
...
$content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
...
```

Creating a Virtual Directories inside of Plesk is not an option, because I do not want to have the site located in a sub-folder of a site.

For whatever it is worth site1/2.com are ASP.Net based so the .Net framework are available if that helps any.

What is another way to achieve the same goal without using SYMLINK, basically on a site that is shared hosting friendly?

Comment: Can you elaborate on _bits and pieces_ ?

Comment: @Amin.T What does bits and pieces mean? I did not use that phrase or anything resembling that phrase.

Comment: You said _"I do not want to embed an entire site, just bits and pieces."_ :)

Comment: you havent specified too well the specifics, but if its just content you are ultimately looking for, maybe the rest-api would be a better method?

Comment: I dont see why you cant put `call a PHP function inside an iframe` on the wordpress site, and then `inside an iframe, which loads the WP content` from the other site.  Basically use an iframe(from the other site)  to run a script on the wordpress site.  Unless your relying on the wordpress session for something it should be fine even with different domains.

Comment: @Amin.T I updated the question; apologies for the delay. The revised question should address your comment.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Hmm, I have to think on your comment a bit, but if I understand what you wrote that might work. I understood to create a webpage on the WP site, which that site does not use and only has the contents of an iframe or just an iframe. The other site would then load that page inside an iframe. That should work. I have to try it. Stay tuned.

Comment: I really think you should be considering @David response, Use the REST api to get those posts and display them anyway you want in your site and maybe link back to their original blog.

Comment: @Amin.T That seems like a lot more work, as I would have to code a server component in PHP, not to mention possibly use some sort of port. The client side would not be too bad as ASP.Net has a REST client. That is as opposed to creating a page that I just call. David did not bother to give any code. I will see tomorrow. I think this approach is virtually no coding, just moving the PHP file from the current location to the blog location and then calling that PHP file.